# Filter criteria affecting different displays in same view

Tags: views

I have a view that displays content in a table form so admins can quickly look through the content. There are two displays (pages).

Page1: Lists all content and exposes the filters for type and published to the user so they can narrow down there view. But initially all content should be displayed.

Page2: Has criteria set to show only type=photo and published=no.(not exposed)

Everything else is the same between the two.

The filters on page2 are affecting page1. When you first land on page1, the filter controls say -any- and -any- but the view is filtered to type=photo and published=no (page2 filters). If you hit apply the filters are removed, but you can see how this could be confusing to users.

How can I prevent the filters on page2 of the view from affecting page1.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you apply any filter criteria / sort criteria / contextual filters / relationships; you have to make sure you apply settings to current display (page/block) only. In this way the current setting doesn't interfere with other displays.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: I did that. In the views configuration page the it does not show up that page1 should be filtered.

Comment: @dan08 It should be good. could you provide export of your view? That way could be easy to debug.

Comment: My bad. published=no was the default for the exposed filter even though it was displaying -any-. And the only unpublished content are photos. It works after changing that.